# What's the best Sharepoint book for developers in C#?

Tags: sharepoint

What's the best Sharepoint 2007 book for developers in C#?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's three I've purchased and found to be very good:

1. [Real World SharePoint 2007: Indispensable Experiences From 16 MOSS and WSS MVPs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470168358)
2. [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201)
3. [SharePoint 2007 User's Guide: Learning Microsoft's Collaboration and Productivity Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598296)

Answer (score 3):

Inside Microsoft® Office SharePoint® Server 2007
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/books/10472.aspx

Inside the Index and Search Engines: Microsoft® Office SharePoint® Server 2007
http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/12195.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Pro SharePoint Solution Development: Combining .NET, SharePoint and Office 2007 (Expert's Voice in Sharepoint)](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590598083)
by: Susie Adams, Ed Hild - ISBN: 1590598083, 9781590598085

Pro SharePoint Solution Development: Combining .NET, SharePoint, and Office 2007 takes a practical problem/solution approach to common business challenges. Youll not only encounter interesting code samples, but also see how to combine these examples with the Microsoft collaboration platforms services. The books solutions focus on using Visual Studio Tools for Office to build the user interface layer. And solutions can interact with SharePoint as a service provider, taking advantage of SharePoints many collaboration features like document repositories, collaboration sites, and search functions.

This book is unique because it starts with challenges that end users deal with every day when using the Microsoft collaboration platform to support business processes. The solutions are presented as the hypothetical business challenges of a fictional company. By presenting the examples in this context, authors Ed Hild and Susie Adams make it easier to relate to the challenges and solution value. And the goal of these examples is to build applications that apply the benefits of the Office desktop interface with the richness of SharePoints collaboration features.

---

[Professional SharePoint 2007 Web Content Management Development: Building Publishing Sites with Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SharePoint-2007-Web-Content-Management-Development-Building-Publishing-Sites-with-Office-SharePoint-Server-2007.productCd-0470224754.html) 
by: Andrew Connell - ISBN: 0470224754, 9780470224755, 9780470396315

This book is for SharePoint developers working with Publishing sites—sites that leverage MOSS 2007 WCM capabilities. It does not cover administrative topics in any great detail, only where absolutely necessary. For the most part, no two chapters are dependent upon each other, so each chapter can be used as a reference independently of the others. Readers need not have any development experience with SharePoint, but they should have some experience with and a working knowledge of ASP.NET 2.0 development practices and topics. Of course, it is beneficial if the reader does have at least a working knowledge of what SharePoint is all about.

This book covers MOSS 2007 WCM Publishing sites. You will find some chapters that seem to cover general WSS 3.0 topics, but everything is treated in the context of a Publishing site. While the chapters are arranged in a logical order, it is not necessary to read the book from cover to cover in a linear fashion.

---

[Advanced SharePoint Services Solutions (Books for Professionals by Professionals)](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590594568)
by: Scot P. Hillier - ISBN: 1590594568, 9781590594568, 9781430200024

Whether or not youve already benefited from Scot P. Hilliers first renowned Apress book, Microsoft SharePoint: Building Office 2003 Solutions, this fantastic follow-up is sure to please! This book will cover advanced techniques for programming web parts and SharePoint Services.

Hillier also covers advanced integration techniques with related products like BizTalk Server 2004 and Content Server. Intended for you advanced developers who already know all of the basic SharePoint Services, this book will steer you to solve ultra-specific, advanced problems.

Answer (score 1):

The Connel and Pattison books listed above are both great, must-read books for SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the Pattison book as mentioned above.  This gives you a great starting point.

[Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201)